# Getting error that my function is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to find weekend days from a table of different dates

I have a solution which is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../homepage.css"
class HomePage extends Component {
    isWorkDay(date, month = 10, year = 2020) {
        const weekDay = new Date(year, month, date).getDay()
        return weekDay !== 0 && weekDay !== 6;
    }
    DateCell({ date }) {
        return <td className={isWorkDay(date) ? 'workday' : 'weekend'}>{date}</td>
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th colSpan="7">Nov</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colSpan="7">Week 1</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            {
                                [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22].map(date => <DateCell key={date} date={date} />)
                            }
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default HomePage;
```

css file:

```
.weekend {
  background-color: pink;
}
.workday {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

But I am getting error:

```
src/components/HomePage.js
  Line 9:31:   'isWorkDay' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 24:75:  'DateCell' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef
```

I just want to know how I can fix this error

Comment: In a class you reference other class members as `this.member` or in your case `this.isWorkDay`. If it does not need to be a class member, you can move it outside the class, use the `function` keyword, and reference it like you have it.

Comment: Move DateCell outside HomePage function.

Comment: Also know that defining a component within a component is an antipattern. You should definitely move `DateCell` outside of the class.

Comment: @lissettdm where should I put DateCell then?

Comment: @BrianThompson please tell me where and how should I put DateCell then?

Comment: Anywhere else. Outside the class, in its own file, it doesn't matter. Just don't put it as a class member.

Answer (score 0):

You can move this functions outside of HomePage component:

```
function isWorkDay(date, month = 10, year = 2020) {
  const weekDay = new Date(year, month, date).getDay();
  return weekDay !== 0 && weekDay !== 6;
}
function DateCell({ date }) {
  return <td className={isWorkDay(date) ? "workday" : "weekend"}>{date}</td>;
}

class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th colSpan="7">Nov</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th colSpan="7">Week 1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              {[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22].map((date) => (
                <DateCell key={date} date={date} />
              ))}
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```